# Error: No executable file specified

Tags: xcode4

Suddenly my program runs and compiles without error but will not open the executable. I get error dialog:

Error Starting Executable... 
No executable file specified. Use the file or exec-file command

I think this may have started when I created a "Workspace" of the same name. I did searches for the error but found nothing that made any sense.

I would hate to have to copy my work over to a new project because of this. Help!

Could this be a bug?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using GDB as default debugger (verify it under Product-Edit Scheme menu) you must specify the executable path that is contained under the app folder (Executable.app/Contents/MacOS/Executable).

Answer (score 0):

Did you add target to your project? If not this might be the problem. Click the project name and then click plus button, then add your target.

Answer (score 0):

Gian Luigi is correct. This is the output from `gdb` if you just run `gdb` and then type `run`.

I tried adding `-exec=/path/to/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp` to the debugger command line but it didn't have any effect.

The easiest solution is to use LLDB instead.